# Finding the nth coordinate where condition is true

Tags: performance, python-3.x, numpy

I have a multidimensional numpy array and I want to find the nth position where a condition is true in a fast way.

If I'd want to find the n'th position where A is zero, in theory I could do

```
coords = np.array(np.where(A==0))
coord = coords[:, n]
```

However, this is terribly slow, because first the condition (A==0) is checked for all entries in A, then all coordinates are generated for these entries, and then all coordinates but the n'th coordinate are discarded.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a native `numpy` way to do this that I can find.  You'll probably need a loopy function in a `numba` wrapper, but I'm not expert enough to give that answer.

Comment: Most of the fast code in numpy works with the whole array - as you describe.  To short-circuit it, especially at the  nth as opposed to the first, you'll have search in compilable code. e.g. with `cython`.